# AWS load balancer redirect www.example.com to example.com isn't working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently have an elastic beanstalk environment.

I've gone to the load balancer settings under EC2, which elastic beanstalk is sitting on.

From there I selected the sole load balancer > Listeners > View/edit rules for both 80 and 443 ports.

I proceeded to add rule where host header is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

I also added a
action: redirect https
port: 443
custom host, path, query: where host was example.com
The redirect selected was a 301.

I proceeded to "add action" for both 80 and 443 listeners.

Problem is it's not working, when I go to http://www.example.com or https://www.example.com, it doesn't go to https://example.com

http://example.com does go to https://example.com

Comment: What are you running in your EB environment? What web server are you using?

Comment: @markwalker_ i'm running a simple nextjs web app

Answer (score -1):

You can add files to your repo which elasticbeanstalk will look for in order to modify the stack.

To do this first add a folder called `.ebextensions` to the root of your project.

In the `.ebextensions` folder create a file called `http-to-https-redirection.config` (or or something that you'll recognise). Then paste the following contents in this file (this is an official [AWS config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-httpredirect.html))

```
Resources:
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: redirect
          RedirectConfig:
            Protocol: HTTPS
            Port: '443'
            Host: '#{host}'
            Path: '/#{path}'
            Query: '#{query}'
            StatusCode: HTTP_301
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
  AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListenerHTTPS:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener'
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: Replace with Certificate ARN
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn:
            Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancerTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
```

You just need to fill in the redirect details which suit what you're doing.

AWS provide further sample config files on github; https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples

Answer (score -1):

The [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#redirect-actions) said you did it in right way. So it's not ALB problem.

I think your EB configuration has some problem (Or maybe DNS as @MarkB said in comments).

For now, only I can say is, basically **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) has nothing to do with example.com** if you don't configure anything.

Do your 'two' domain(`www.example.com` and `example.com`) points same page which is hosted by EB?

Comment: how can i diagnose this?

Comment: That wouldn't be an EB configuration problem, it would be a DNS configuration problem.

Comment: @MarkB do you mean i should go to route 53, go to the designated hosted zone, create an A record and point the alias to the load balancer?

Comment: @MarkB Would you pick up which problem on DNS you have doubt on? Maybe it could be caused by DNS but I have no idea about that way.

Comment: @ShaunChua Actually there are bunch of other way to do what you want. Using Route53 could be the one. But I'm more interested in understanding why your approach is not woring.

Comment: There is nothing in EB that would "block the request from pass through the configured LB" as you state in your answer, since the request would go through the LB before it ever gets to the EB environment. The only thing that would block a request for a specific domain name from going to the load balancer is if the domain's DNS is not properly setup to point to that load balancer.

Comment: @ShaunChua quick question: are you using your own domain instead of default one which EB provides? If so, how it is connected with your EB?

Comment: @MarkB you're right. when I wrote that answer, it was a kind of metaphorical diagnosis. It seems so confusing that I would edit my answer. Thank you for pointing out